# Trouble implementing android_serialport_api into my own application

Tags: android, android-studio, serial-port, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am currently working on an embedded system for my company that runs the android 4.2 OS (from TI bbb source) on the Beaglebone black. I have been tasked with setting up communication with the serial port (UART). I have been able to configure the serial port and run the android_serial_port_api (https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/) sample application flawlessly. Where I am having trouble is when I try to write my own application using this API. I do not quite understand the idea of using an API (especially a third party one). I am using Android Studio to develop and have copied all of the source code from the sample application and am now attempting to alter it to my own needs. I know this is most likely a stupid question, but my research on how to fix it is running me in circles. Any and all help is more than welcome.

edit: tried to include image, but have too low a rep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Module using the third party library and include in your project. Now you can start importing the classes directly from the third party library. Android studio has options to create a new module from the current project.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried to do that, but wasn't quite sure what portion of the file I downloaded to include. Also when I try to compile the project in the build.gradle I have issues. I am including what my file tree looks like right now in hopes that it provides some more insight

Comment: I added a module of type android library and included the source code. I was then able to import the package into my original app for use. now just need to figure out why its crashing when i try and employ the sending01010101 action